# PHP Regex — Remove all characters but first from last word in string

Tags: php, regex, string, character, trim

I researched quite a long time before posting, but I couldn't come up with an answer.

I'm trying to remove all characters but the first from a string. The string is going to be a name. The name can have a first name and a last name, as well as a middle name. So my task is to explode the string into words and find the last one, remove the characters and add a dot to the first letter. Moreover, if present in the string, the middle name should not be in the result.

For example: `Chuck Ray Norris` should transform into `Chuck N.`

I tried a couple of `regex` and `strpos` but this task is too difficult for me and my skills.

Comment: You say you tried some stuff. Show us that stuff. Faulty or not, it's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [non-regex solution](https://ideone.com/8rgcA5) for "FirstName SecondName ThirdName... LastName" pattern:

```
<?php
$str = "Chuck Ray Norris";
$spls = explode(" ", $str);
echo $spls[0] . " " . $spls[count($spls)-1][0] . ".";
```

Output:

```
Chuck N.
```

Comment: You are welcome. Still, please add what you tried to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$s = 'Chuck Ray Norris';
$r = preg_replace('/^(\S+)\s+(?:\S+\s+)*(\S)\S*$/', '$1 $2.', $s);
//=> Chuck N.

$s = 'Chuck Norris';
$r = preg_replace('/^(\S+)\s+(?:\S+\s+)*(\S)\S*$/', '$1 $2.', $s);
//=> Chuck N.

$s = 'Chuck N.';
$r = preg_replace('/^(\S+)\s+(?:\S+\s+)*(\S)\S*$/', '$1 $2.', $s);
//=> Chuck N.
```

`(?:\S+\s+)*` is used for making 1 or more middle names optional. It also takes care of the case when name is already in desired format (case 3 above).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this will work, but try this

```
<?php

$fullName = 'Chuck Ray Norris';
//$fullName = 'Chuck Ray';
//$fullName = 'Chuck';

$names = explode(' ', $fullName);
if((count($names) == 3) && isset($names[2])){
    echo $names[0] . ' ' . $names[2][0] . '.';
}else{
    if((count($names) == 2) && isset($names[1])){
        echo $names[0] . ' ' . $names[1][0] . '.';
    }else{
        echo $names[0];
    }
}

?>
```

try to change the $fullName to 'Chuck Ray' or 'Chuck' its still working also.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if it is just a string with the requirements:

> Chuck Ray Norris -> Chuck N

Then using [explode()](http://php.net/explode), [substr()](http://php.net/substr) and [strlen()](http://php.net/strlen):

```
<?php
  $string = "Chuck Ray Norris";

  // break string into words
  $array = explode(" ", $string);

  // keep the first word, keep the last word's first character
  // ensure we have broken into vaid parts
  $length = count($array);
  if($length > 2) {
    // ie. Chuck Norris
    $first_word = $array[0];
    $last_word = $array[$length-1];

    // get first character, 
    $first_character = substr($last_word, 0, 1);
  }
  // else case is omitted

  print "$first_word $first_character\n"; // outputs Chuck N

?>
```

> string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

**Ex:** `substr($last_word, 0, 1)`

- `int $start`: the length of "Norris" is 6, so first position is 0
- `int $length`: we need only 1 character, therefore position 0, "N";

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$pos = strrpos($string, " ");

$pos = $pos === false ? 0 : $pos + 1;

$char = substr($string,$pos,1);
```